# How to increase top menu bar width in gnome?

Tags: gnome, gui, gnome-tweaks

On my Ubuntu 20.04 with 4K monitor, the top bar is quite narrow which makes it difficult to click a tab.

[image]

I know how to increase the width of the interface fonts using `gnome-tweaks` tool but it is still ugly as the large font tabs seem to be trapped in still narrow menu.

So I'm wondering how to change the padding of tabs or increase the width of the menu directly?